# How to prevent Razor from escaping an ampersand, such as in &nbsp;?

Tags: html, razor, razorengine

I'm parsing a Razor template that contains code such as

```
@model.Field
```

When `Field` includes a `&nbsp;`, it gets escaped and turns into `&amp;nbsp;`.

How do I apply a real non-breaking space and prevent the escaping of `&`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw(model.Field)`.

It will prevent HTML encoding of your data (which happens by default since Razor v3).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) and this [Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) by Phil Haack.

**update**

I now see you're using RazorEngine. In RazorEngine you can just use the built-in Raw method like this: `@Raw(model.Field)`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using `RazorEngine` and I have no access to `System.Web.Mvc`.